# I can't see the bordercolor attribute in code completion in PhpStorm

Tags: html, colors, attributes, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm 2017.2.4.

When I write `<table>` tags and type space to insert some attributes like `bordercolor`, I cant see `bordercolor` attribute in code completion, but it shows in Adobe DreamWeaver CC.

When I wrote `bordercolor` manually PhpStorm displays a warning

> Attribute bordercolor is not allowed here

I changed **Default HTML language level** to HTML 4.0  in: **File | Settings | Language & Frameworks| Schemas and DTDs| Default XML Schemas** but only warning was disabled and `bordercolor` did not appear in code completion list yet.

Why is this problem? How can I solve it?

I use CSS but I want to change border-color of one of the tables differently from the base of the styles created.

Comment: Code samples/screenshots please -- need to see the context -- maybe you are doing something wrong (there is always a chance for that).

Comment: Why not use CSS for that (in a .css file .. or at very least in `style` attribute for `<table>` if you want to hardcode it)? `bordercolor` attribute is deprecated AFAIK -- I do not see it in allowed attribute list in HTML 4 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1.

Comment: **I use CSS but  I want to change border-color of one of the tables differently from the base of the styles created**                          . I'm afraid some of the old PHP and HTML codes and tags that I knew well, would not be on the list, and I have to learn things that are my scheduled plan for after the completion of this project and for now I dont have enough time to learn new content.

Comment: `<table style="border-color: #eee;">....</table>` -- pretty similar to what you are trying to use with `bordercolor="#eee"`

Comment: **thanks.I knew that.I want to know how can I set phpstorm to appear old tags and codes in code completion. Is there a way to do this???**

Comment: You already have an answer from Lena (she is from WebStorm team) -- as for me it's pretty clear what can be done here.

Answer (score 2):

This attribute is non-standard, not a part of HTML spec, implemented differently by different browsers. so, in general, it's not recommended to use it, try using [CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) instead.
But, if you need using it for some special reason, try adding it to custom HTML attributes: hit `Alt+Enter` on attribute highlighted as not allowed, choose to add it to custom attributes:

[image]

Custom attributes are no reported as unknown and are available in completion